# Unsupported operand type(s) in formula

Tags: python, formula, operand

I m having problems getting python 2.7 to do this formula. Its purpose is to convert Landsat 7 DN values to reflectance values. b1 references a band1 TIFF image.

```
L_B1 = float(((LMax_B1 - LMin_B1) / (QCALMax_B1 - QCALMin_B1)) * (b1 - QCALMin_B1) + LMin_B1)
```

The error message I m getting is:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

It appears to not like - / * . Ive imported math.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you are operating on strings, that is either one of your variables like `LMax_B1` etc. is a unicode string, or probably all of them are. You have to convert them to floating point numbers (or whatever they are) first, i.e. change:

```
LMax_B1 - LMin_B1
```

to

```
float(LMax_B1) - float(LMin_B1)
```

Do so likewise for all other variables. By the way, you don't need to import math for the operators `+ - * /`. They are always available and work as expected if you operate on numbers. Math is required for more advanced functions like `sin` etc.

Comment: Hi Johannes, your right my variables were strings but i changed them to float when they are created. I did as you said regarding adding float but I get TypeError : float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: It might be that not all of your variables are unicode strings. Could you just print all variables, or even better: print type(QCALMax_B1) ?

Comment: The result is type float. However b1 is a list. [u'LE71460402013077PFS00_B1.TIF'] So this is the problem. B1 should reference the band 1 image that I want to perform the calculations on. I don't know how else to do it. Should I be using another module?

Comment: It looks like the filename of a TIFF image. There is a Python library to deal with those images, called PIL (Python imaging library) http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-tiff.htm , however this is where my PythonFu ends. Anyway, I think it's not possible to just subtract a floating point number from an image.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. I m in a better position than I was. Cheers.